# Where can I ask questions about biology?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have the DNA sequence of a virus and I want to ask for a software recommendation where I can convert the genome into a 3D model. But I don't know where to ask it. I asked it on Stack Overflow and it was flagged off-topic (which it was...) So, can anybody point me in the right direction as to where I need to ask questions like this, associated with biology?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Biology questions can be asked on [Biology Stack Exchange](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Bioinformations questions in particular can be asked on [Bioinformatics Stack Exchange](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (although many bioinformatics questions are still on-topic for Biology).

However, neither of these sites are going to accept software recommendation questions. You *might* be able to ask on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but you need to carefully follow their [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

In your case, Google might be a better tool than Stack Exchange. A quick Google search turns up [this question on ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_someone_suggest_any_software_for_3D_DNA_modeling). I also find references to a tool called Graphite-MicroMégas, which is designed for creating 3D models of DNA and proteins.

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason, I couldn't find the biology stack exchange. But thanks again for the help :)